# How to create a backend to hide API keys in Reactjs app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am currently developing an app using Reactjs. I had hidden my API keys and AWS keys in the dotenv file. But I just realized that this was absolutely not secured. My current set up is that my app is running in an S3 bucket on AWS, and I was wondering if I could use my EC2 instance to hide my keys from users, but still being able to get them in the app.

This is the first time I am developing an app in Reactjs and I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Use back end as a proxy to access remote api. Then the keys stay on server away from prying eyes

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to try and find out how to do this... do you know of any examples/tutorials/documentation on the subject ?

Comment: SHould be easy to research .. "ajax proxy" or add "javascript" to it. Concept is failry straightforward....your client app requests from your own endpoint and that in turn uses keys to make server to server request and return response to client app

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ! It's the first time I am asking a question here though, is there anything else I should do to close the thread, and to thank you (like votes/points ?) or anything ?

Comment: No. Overall question is generally a bit too broad for posting an actual answer and as such doesn't have a lot of long term value for others in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at AWS Amplify, it makes that process super easy.

Using React & AWS Amplify, you can create a serverless architecture for this type of setup with minimal work.  You can get started by following the instructions at https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/

In a nutshel :

Install with:

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
$ amplify configure
```

Then in your project :

```sh
amplify init 
amplify add api #this will create your API as AWS Lambda functions exposed through Amazon API Gateway)
amplify push #to create all this on your AWS account for you
```

If you search for 'aws amplify react' you will easily find a dozen blog posting showing you how to get started.  There are so many I can not recommend one in particular.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot I'll look into it. This seems like a "simpler" way to do it.